# How to use variables inside the key of an update query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, backend

I'm updating documents by two hardcoded indexes (0 and 0 in `$set`) and it works just fine.

```
var result = db.collection('users', function (err, update_node) {
  update_node
    .updateOne(
      {
        _id: ObjectID(req.body.userid),
        "portfolio.nodes.node_id": ObjectID(req.body.nodeid)
      },
      {
        $set: {
          "portfolio.0.nodes.0.node_name": req.body.node_name
        }
      }
    )
    .then(function (doc) {
      res.send(doc);
    });
});
```

How can I use index1 and index2 inside of $set?

```
const index1 = 0;
const index2 = 0;

var result = db.collection('users', function (err, update_node) {
  update_node
    .updateOne(
      {
        _id: ObjectID(req.body.userid),
        "portfolio.nodes.node_id": ObjectID(req.body.nodeid)
      },
      {
        $set: {
          'portfolio.index1.nodes.index2.node_name': req.body.node_name
        }
      }
    )
    .then(function (doc) {
      res.send(doc);
    });
});
```

I also tried positional operators:

```
'portfolio.$.nodes.$.node_name': req.body.node_name
```

But it looks like there is no way to use multiple positional operators in MongoDB.
Thank you so much.

Comment: `[portfolio.index1.nodes.index2.node_name]: req.body.node_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

```
let index1 = 0;
let index2 = 0;
let set = {
  ["portfolio."+index1+".nodes."+index2+".node_name"]: req.body.node_name
};

update_node.updateOne(
  {
    _id: ObjectID(req.body.userid),
    "portfolio.nodes.node_id": ObjectID(req.body.nodeid)
  },
  { $set: set }
)
.then(function (doc) { res.send(doc); });
```

---

Conclusion on your query, you can not use more than one `$` positional operator, but you can use single positional operator and [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) together,

```
update_node.update(
  {
    _id: ObjectID(req.body.userid),
    "portfolio.nodes.node_id": ObjectID(req.body.nodeid)
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "portfolio.$.nodes.$[n].node_name": req.body.node_name
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "n.node_id": ObjectID(req.body.nodeid) }
    ]
  }
)
.then(function (doc) { res.send(doc); });
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CYQc8aHS9wy)

Comment: Thank you very much! Positional operator together with arrayFilters is the best solution for me. Works! :)